# Create a hotspot on the edge on top of all apps that can be swiped on Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I would like to develop an app that is very simple.

All it does is put a hotspot (at a user specified y coordinate, user specified width and user specified left or right edge of the screen).

When the user swipes across this hotspot, it expands horizontally into a seek bar (like one for brightness).

A similar app would be [Switchr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mohammad.adib.switchr), but I'd like to use the edge swipes for a different purpose (not for switching apps).

Anyone know how I could go about doing this? Or if there any open source resources that I could learn from?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by requesting the "draw over other apps" permission ([SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)). This allows you to place your layouts over other applications.

Try the [StandOut](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut/) library, it will probably meet your requirements and save you a lot of coding.

Comment: Interesting I will check it out. I don't want a floating window just a hotspot on the edge, but if I can make that happen with this library that'd be awesome. Also thanks for letting me know about the permission.

Comment: Yes, in your case you could use a transparent window, I guess.